# Error at startup running War Thunder

Tags: 12.04, opengl

Hello Who can help me to solve this error?

```
Error initializing video (OpenGL3):
../../prog/engine2/drv/drv3d_GL3/linux_main.cpp, 415: error when creating of gl_context
```

Comment: Please expand on your question. What were you trying to do that gave the error?

Comment: You need to give more info.  I googled the error and find it could be related to the graphics card drivers.  What are your specs on the PC and specifically the graphics card?  This actually may be a better place for you to start:  http://forum.warthunder.com/  My google search showed this issue appearing in their forums.

Comment: @john yea I found this thread http://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/244920-videomode-initialization-error/ but I am still searching for fix

Answer (score 0):

Found a thread from forum.warthunder.com, there was indication that it may be that the graphics card does not meet requirements.

If this is the case, it would have been to nice to have that as the message pop up...In any case I will look further into this for a more definitive answer.

https://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/244629-cannot-start-game-on-ibmz61m-with-radeon-mobility-x1400/

The hardware/software requirements  can be found at :
http://warthunder.com/cs/game/requirements

Currently it states:

**For Linux & SteamOS:**

*Minimum:*

- OS: Most modern 64bit Linux distributions, SteamOS
- Processor: Dual-Core 2,4 GHz
- Memory: 4 GB
- Video Card: Intel 4000 HD/Radeon HD 5550/GeForce 8800
- Network: Broadband Internet connection
- Hard Drive: 11 GB

*Recommended:*

- Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, SteamOS
- Processor: Intel Core i7
- Memory: 8 GB
- Video Card: Nvidia GeForce 660+ or similar AMD
- Network: Broadband Internet connection
- Hard Drive: 11 GB

Seems that this (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/steam#Steam_runtime_issues) should help but I have yet to figure it out

Basically it is suggested some of the libraries are old and bundled with steam, so supposedly you remove the (linux) packages provided by steam and    the system should automatically attempt to use the system ones, and all should work.

Here is the instruction part:

> Run this command to remove the runtime libraries known to cause issues
>   on Arch Linux:
>
> ```
> find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" \) -print -delete
> ```
>
> If the above command does not work, run the above command again, then
>   run this command.
>
> ```
> find ~/.local/share/Steam/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" \) -print -delete
> ```